# "map" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app:2 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Tags: nginx, meteor, ubuntu-14.04

> user www-data;
>       worker_processes auto;
>       pid /run/nginx.pid;
>
> ```
> events {
>         worker_connections 768;
>         # multi_accept on;
> }
>
> http {
>         # this section is needed to proxy web-socket connections
>         map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
>                 default upgrade;
>                   ''      close;
>         }
>
>         ##
>         # Basic Settings
>         ##
>
>         sendfile on;
>         tcp_nopush on;
>         tcp_nodelay on;
>         keepalive_timeout 65;
>         types_hash_max_size 2048;
>         # server_tokens off;
>
>         # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
>         # server_name_in_redirect off;
>
>         include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>         default_type application/octet-stream;
>
>         ##
>         # SSL Settings
>         ##
>
>         ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
>         ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>
>         ##
>         # Logging Settings
>         ##
>
>         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
>         error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
>
>         ##
>         # Gzip Settings
>         ##
>         include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
>         gzip on;
>         gzip_disable "msie6";
>         # gzip_vary on;
>         # gzip_proxied any;
>         # gzip_comp_level 6;
>         # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
>         # gzip_http_version 1.1;
>         # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
>           application/javascript text/xml application/xml applicatio
>         n/xml+rss text/javascript;
>         ##
>         # Virtual Host Configs
>         ##
>         include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
>         include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
> }
> #mail {
> #       # See sample authentication script at:
> #       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
> # 
> #       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
> #       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
> #       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
> # 
> #       server {
> #               listen     localhost:110;
> #               protocol   pop3;
> #               proxy      on;
> #       }
> # 
> #       server {
> #               listen     localhost:143;
> #               protocol   imap;
> #               proxy      on;
> #       }
> #}
> include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
> ```

Deploying meteor with nginx web server :
This my nginx.config file , I am getting follwing error ""map" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/app:2 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed" while executing "**sudo nginx -t**"

Comment: You have two `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` lines - delete the last one.

Comment: removed it still not working

Comment: Remove _and_ restart nginx!